# Make a div stick to bottom of parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a layout here which looks like the following: Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHUQQ/)

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            This is the content section
        </div>
        <div class="stream-content">
                This is the stream content.
        </div>
        <div class="push">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">  
    </div>
<body>
```

I want the `content section` to take up the full space between the `header` and `footer` section. There is an additional section called [`stream-content`] which if there (will be there only on home page) has to take the position just before the `footer`. And in that case, the `content` section should take up space all the between `header` and `stream-content` section. I tried doing the same with absolute positioning but all my elements were going haywire, so wanted to understand the correct way of doing this. Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: You could always make the height of your div's in percents. Header 5%, body 90%, footer 5%. I am not sure if percents are frowned upon, but it should work.

Comment: [this may help](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/9DLeg/) - just put the content and stream content into the middle section

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to your wraper class.
Add `position:absolute;bottom:0;` to the stream-content class.

Check it here.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHUQQ/2/)

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response. But I noticed the red footer that I thought was sticky is going down as well when I add a lot of matter in the `content` section. I had made that sticky footer looking at css-tricks here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ but it longer seems to be working now. Is there something that I missed here? Would be great to get some help.

Comment: So you want it to stick to the bottom of the browser or the bottom of the wraper?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the wrapper. `fixed` position is relative to the screen's viewport, not element's parent.

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli Your answer has 2 upvotes and 0 downvotes. The answer is wrong and misleading though. If I were you I would consider fixing it.

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli position fixed is wrong, this is position absolute

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then one way to do it would be to put [steam content] outside the wrapper, as wrapper is the one that is keeping the footer at the bottom. If you must have the [steam content] inside wrapper than you can try something like this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ to keep it at the bottom together with the footer

Comment: Link broken. I would try to find an archived version but it's robots.txt disallows indexing.

Comment: There seems to be a copy here https://wiki.edgarbv.com/index.php/CSS_Sticky_Footer